# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Computing a value in Razor and rending the result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm retrieving data from my database and on a particular entity I have a property called gender where I store either the letter M or F, however I want to display the full description so that M = Male, and F = Female. I've attempted the following code however it doesn't work, any ideas as to why?

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender == "M" ? "male" : "female")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by the following code

```
@(Model.Gender == "M" ? "male" : "female")
```

hope this helps